# Ensuring Document is Retrieved Without Using setTimeout() in Mocha Test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have written some tests in my Node project using Mocha and Chai. In one of my tests I create an agenda.js job, and then save it to the database. Then I retrieve that document from my MongoDB database and run some checks on it. After numerous configurations, I've found a construction for the test that works. But to get this to work I had to add a `setTimeout()` within the first `it` block, because otherwise the `it` checks start running before the document is retrieved from the database.

While the following construction works, I'd like to know what would be a better way of doing this. It seems to me the whole point of the `before` block in Mocha is to ensure that whatever work is defined within it is done *BEFORE* the `it` checks run. That doesn't seem to be happening in my case - hence the need for the `setTimeout()`. So how can I accomplish that without resorting to using the `setTimeout()?:

```
const assert = require("chai").assert;
const expect = require("chai").expect;
const chai = require("chai");
chai.use(require("chai-datetime"));
const Agenda = require('agenda');

const config = require('./../../configuration');
const url = config.get('MONGO_URL');
const dbName = config.get('MONGO_DATABASE');
const collection = config.get('MONGO_COLLECTION');
const createAgendaJob = require('./../../lib/agenda-jobs/contact-firstname-to-proper-case');

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(url);

describe("Contact FirstName to Proper Case", async function () {
  const jobName = "Contact FirstName To Proper Case";
  const testDate = new Date(2019, 01, 01);
  let result;
  let agenda;
  this.timeout(10000);
  before(async function () {
    const connectionOpts = {
      db: {
        address: `${url}/${dbName}`,
        collection
      }
    };

    agenda = new Agenda(connectionOpts);
    await new Promise(resolve => agenda.once('ready', resolve));
    await createAgendaJob(agenda);
  });
  describe("Check Contact FirstName To ProperCase Found Job", async function () {
    let result;
    before(async function () {
      await client.connect(async function (err) {
        assert.equal(null, err);

        const db = await client.db(dbName);

        result = await db.collection("jobs").findOne({
          "name": jobName
        });

        client.close();
      });
    });
    it("should have a property 'name'", async function () {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // Here is the setTimout()
      expect(result).to.have.property("name");
    });
    it("should have a 'name' of 'Contact FirstName To Proper Case'", async function () {
      expect(result.name).to.equal("Contact FirstName To Proper Case");
    });
    it("should have a property 'type'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("type");
    });
    it("should have a 'type' of 'normal'", function () {
      expect(result.type).to.equal("normal");
    });
    it("should have a property 'repeatTimezone'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("repeatTimezone");
    });
    it("should have a property 'repeatInterval'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("repeatInterval");
    });
    it("should have a property 'lastModifiedBy'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("lastModifiedBy");
    });
    it("should have a property 'nextRunAt'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("nextRunAt");
    });
    it("should return a date for the 'nextRunAt' property", function () {
      assert.typeOf(result.nextRunAt, "date");
    });
    it("should 'nextRunAt' to be a date after test date", function () {
      expect(result.nextRunAt).to.afterDate(testDate);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Personally I would just use the 'done' callback like this: `before(function(done){ /* some awaiting async code, done(err) */ });`

Comment: I'm using async/await - so it should be equally effective. Either one handles async code and ensures the code is executed before moving on. I will try it though - to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: ok, you have the outer before seems to be working fine, so what's different about the inner before?
Is `client.connect` resolving before the awaits inside the async callback that gets passed to it?

Comment: I tried using the done() callback instead of the promise-based async/await construction in the `before` block. Exactly same result. Only works with the addition of the `setTimeout()` block.

Comment: I don't know. But regardless, why would the `it` block run before *everything* defined in the `before` block is completed?

Comment: try returning the await in the before

Comment: There are two awaits there. Which one do you mean?

Comment: the _it_ will run before the _before_ has finished an async function if the _before_ is returned a resolved promise.

Comment: The final await

Comment: Okay, so what do you suggest? I tried explicitly returning `result` in the `before` block. Still didn't work. The second half of the `it` checks pass, because it resolves half-way through those checks being run currently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201412/discussion-between-george-and-muirik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async function inside before may be resolving early. In that case I would wrap it in a new Promise and resolve when I am sure all async code has resolved to completion.

```js
//...
before(function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.connect(async function (err) {
      if(err) return reject(err);
      try {
        const db = await client.db(dbName);

        result = await db.collection("jobs").findOne({
        "name": jobName
        });

        client.close();
      } catch(err){
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve();
    });
  });
})
//...
```

Alternatively, call the `done` callback, passing in a truthy value if there is an error.

```js
//...
before(function (done) {
  client.connect(async function (err) {
    if(err) return done(err);
    try {
      const db = await client.db(dbName);

      result = await db.collection("jobs").findOne({
      "name": jobName
      });

      client.close();
    } catch(err){
      return done(err);
    }
    done();
  });
})
//...
```